# How to sumif with array or sumproduct

Tags: excel

I have some products and each products are made of one or more parts. I attached a sample. [image]

For example, product A is made of one part "a11" and client ordered 10, Product B is made of 2 part "a12" and client ordered 20...... product E is made of 2 part "a15" and 3 part "a16"and client ordered 50.

I have a second table to summarize how many parts in total do I need `(E1:F7)`. I want to do formula `=sumif($B$2:$B$7,$E2,sumproduct(C2:$C$7,D2:D7))` to see the total of each part I need but it doesn't work, anyone knows any formula that can help me with this problem?

Comment: In cell E2, don't you just need `=D2*C2` and then copy down?

Comment: Just use SUMPRODUCT: `=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$7=$E2)*C2:$C$7,D2:D7)`

Comment: Yes I can, but the D2:D7 part is dynamic meaning if I have another month of orders D2:D7 will be E2:E7

Comment: @ScottCraner, yes your formula works great, thank you! Just a follow up question. The sheet like the one shown in the picture is for one client, and I have 20 clients so I have 20 sheets. I want to do one summary sheet to show the total number of each part I need through all 20 clients, how should I do it? Can I sumproduct through multiple sheets?